# Can I access a private class method from a public instance method without using the class name?

Tags: ruby

I have a class method, `self.calculate`, that I want to invoke from both another class method and from an instance method.

If I write

```
def green
  calculate(x,y,z)
end
```

though, I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'calculate'` exception. Invoking `self.calculate` gets the same problem.

What *does* work is calling `MyClassName.calculate`, but that seems somehow wrong and messy. What is the correct practice in this situation?

Comment: Umm ... `MyClassName.calculate` should *not* work if `calculate` is `private` as you claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
self.class.calculate
```

to call a class methods from an instance method.